# How to make a parent RoundedRectView as tall as the UILabelView that it contains?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uikit

I have a parent RoundedRectView that contains a UILabelView of varying height. Depending on the contents and height of the UILabelView, I want to adjust the RoundedRectView accordingly.

How do I get about doing that?

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If its just that you want the UILabel to draw you can just set the clipToBounds property of the parent view to no. Otherwise the child view can change it's parent view's frame like any other

```
CGRect parentFrame = [self superview].frame;
// change parent frame
[self superview].frame = parentFrame;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not have a custom UILabel subclass and draw your rounded rectangle in there, rather than having two views?

It's not clear what visual effect you are aiming for, but a simple border which is a rounded rectangle could even be achieved just by looking at the `CALayer` of your label.